# Mac OS X theme for Lubuntu does not change the look of Window Borders

Tags: lubuntu, themes, lxde

So I found this really good looking theme in [here](http://www.linuxslaves.com/2016/05/macbuntu-mac-os-x-yosmite-theme-for-ubuntu1604.html) :

I followed the steps, and instead of installing and using unity-theme-utility I used

```
Preferences > Customize Look and Feel
```

However, even do that theme was LXDE compatible, I did not get the result I expected, indeed the window borders do not look like in the first link:

[image: screenshot]

How do I solve this problem? Do I have to install additional software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this theme is not compatible with LXDE, so I installed Xfce, configured things well and everything was working properly.

Comment: This theme lacks openbox-3 folder, implying it doesn't have the definitions for `openbox` window manager. You can install another window manager to use it, like `metacity`. After that you can use metacity with this theme in Lubuntu